# How to write an expression to a file?

Tags: python, file-writing

Here's my code:

```
import COVID19Py
import random

covid19 = COVID19Py.COVID19()

source = random.choice(['jhu', 'csbs', 'nyt'])
covid19 = COVID19Py.COVID19(data_source=source)
latest = covid19.getLatest()
f = open("CoronavirusDeathsT.txt", "a")
f.write(latest)
f.close()
```

I want to use f.write() to write `latest` to the text document but I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\AcerPC\OneDrive\Documents\Codes\CoronaVirusTest.py", line 9, in <module>
    f.write(latest)
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not dict
```

Comment: `json.dump(latest, f)`

Comment: `f.write(str(latest))` might work, depending on what's in the dictionary.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @roundtables! I recommend you to read the help page [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Have a nice trip on SO.

Comment: What's in the dict and what's its structure? CSV and JSON would work on the simpler end, otherwise `pickle` might work.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says, `latest` is a `dict`, that is, a data structure that maps one or more *keys* to corresponding *values*:

```
{
   key1: value1,
   key2: value2
}
```

You cannot directly write a `dict` to a file, since the writer wouldn't know how to convert these keys and values to text (to put it simply).

So how to proceed? It depends on how `latest` is structured and what you want to do with your file in the end. Here are two of the many options:

- Using the data in other apps, e.g. for visualization? Export as JSON:

  ```
  import json
  [...]
  json.dump(latest, f)
  ```
- Using it in a spreadsheet context? Export as CSV:

  *Note: this doesn't work well if the dict is nested, i.e. contains other dict as values*

  See Python's [csv.DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) class and it's easy-to-understand example code. Your can get the required fieldnames (spreadsheet column names) directly from your data like this:

  ```
  fieldnames = list(latest.keys())
  ```

---

PS: You should have a look at the data first by simply printing it:

```
import json
print(json.dumps(latest, indent=4))
```

Answer (score 0):

`f.write` only writes a string so you need to convert your dictionary into string. Try this.

```
import json
f.write(json.dumps(latest))
```